# Google Sceneform Tools

Tags: android-studio, 3d, ar

Android studio. Установил плагин Google Sceneform Tools, нажимаю правой кнопкой на fbx файл (3д модель) выбираю Import Google Asset, далее настраиваю путь в папку raw, нажимаю finish... иии... ничего не происходит, всё перезагружал, плагин переустанавливал (1.15.0 стоит). Сама камера при компиляции работает и хорошо всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution - add to the gradle (app) ----

apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/bear.fbx', // 'Source Asset Path' specified during import.
'default',                            // 'Material Path' specified during import.
'sampledata/models/bear.sfa',         // '.sfa Output Path' specified during import.
'src/main/res/raw/bear')              // '.sfb Output Path' specified during import.

and press make project